# How to write Haskell-do-notation in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell

I wrote the following Haskell code using do-nation.

And I'd like to convert it to Scala code

```haskell
main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ func1 (Right  1) (Right 2)
  print $ func1 (Right 10) (Right 3)


func1 :: Either String Int -> Either String Int -> Either String Double
func1 e1 e2 = do
  v1 <- e1
  v2 <- e2
  if v1 < v2
    then Right 1.515151  -- No meaning
    else Left  "some error"
```

Here is output of Haskell

```
Right 1.515151
Left "some error"
```

I wrote Scala code like the following. But I feel weird when I look at `result <- if(v1 < v2)...` and `yield result`.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(func1(Right(1))(Right(2)))
    println(func1(Right(10))(Right(3)))
  }

  def func1(e1: Either[String, Int])(e2: Either[String, Int]): Either[String, Double] =
    for{
      v1 <- e1
      v2 <- e2

      // Weird...
      result <- if(v1 < v2)
                  Right(1.515151)
                else
                  Left("some error")
    } yield result
}
```

Here is output of Scala

```
Right(1.515151)
Left(some error)
```

I'd like to write bellow. But Scala doesn't allow me to write.

```
  // Invalid Scala Code
  def func1(e1: Either[String, Int])(e2: Either[String, Int]): Either[String, Double] =
    for{
      v1 <- e1
      v2 <- e2
    } {
      if(v1 < v2)
          Right(1.515151)
        else
          Left("some error")
    }
```

Could you tell me your idea for writing in beautiful way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be prettified some.

```
for {
  v1  <- e1
  v2  <- e2
  res <- Either.cond(v1 < v2, 1.515151, "some error")
} yield res
```

It would be nice to just throw in a guard condition but, according to the [Scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html), that's not supported because `Either` has no `withFilter` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, jwvh! I don't know `Either.cond`. Actually I'd like to use `EitherT` in scalaz instead of `Either`, so I searched for `Either.cond` alternative in `EitherT` but I couldn't find it. Could you tell me if you know?

Comment: Sorry, don't know scalaz. It's on my TODO list.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I don't know Haskell, so I may be wrong with this)

The difference between Haskell's `do` notation, and Scala's `for`/`yield` comprehension is that `do` sequence ends with a `bind` (i.e. `flatMap`), but `for`/`yield` ends with a normal `map`.

So in Haskell if you have a pure value in the last step, you have to wrap it in `return`, but in Scala you can `yield` it directly. `yield` is a keyword, not a function like Haskell's `return`. On the other hand, when in the last step you have a monadic value, in Haskell you can just put it there, but in Scala you have to add a step with `result <- monadicValue` and then `yield result`.

This is just a difference in design in those two languages, and I believe you just have to get used to how Scala does this.

---

As for your question in the comment to the other answer:

In scalaz instead of `Either.cond(p, a, b)` you can use `p.either(a).or(b)`, which returns a disjunction:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> true.either(10).or("error")
res0: scalaz.\/[String,Int] = \/-(10)
```

Then you can wrap this disjunction in the monad you want, and then in `EitherT`. For example:

```
scala> EitherT(true.either(10).or("error").some)
res1: scalaz.EitherT[Option,String,Int] = EitherT(Some(\/-(10)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kolmar~ `p.either(a).or(b)` is what I want. Thank you!  

>> I believe you just have to get used to how Scala does this.
I want to do.

Comment: Are there `match-case` version? The last expression of my code is `if`, but are there any `match-case`  version in scalaz?

Comment: `match-case` version means `v1 < v2 match {case true => Right(1.515151); case false => Left("some error")}`. (This example can be replaced with `if`, but this is just an example.)